# How can I call a method for all instances of a class, which are together in a list?

Tags: java

For my little game, I have an ArrayList called "walls" in my main-class, to hold all instances of the class "Wall".

The first part of sample:

```
walls = new ArrayList<>();
```

The second part of the sample:

```
wall = new Wall(x, y);
walls.add(wall);
```

This code is located in the main-class

The actual variables of the wall (class Wall) and walls (ArrayList) are located above the constructor of the main class, so they can be used in multiple methods of the main class

The bottom two lines of this sample are called several times during the level-setup.
each instance of Wall is one wall-tile in a square grid and together they make the level-map

How do I call a method (that changes the wall-graphic) of the Wall-class in all it´s instances in the list?

The method in the Wall-class is finished and works.
But I don’t know, how to call it for all members of that ArrayList.

Comment: `for (Wall wall : walls){wall.someMethod();}`

Comment: If you didn't know what loops were for, now you know. Use a loop. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply as:

```
List<Walls> walls = new ArrayList<>();

...

Wall wall = new Wall(x, y);
walls.add(wall);

...
# Java <8 Flavour
for (Wall wall :  walls) {
   wall.yourMethod();
}

# Java > 8 Flavour:

walls.stream().forEach(w -> w.yourMethod()));
```

Comment: The first is actually OK for all Java versions >= 5. The second is actually OK for all Java versions >= 8. And there is no need for `.stream()`.

Answer (score 0):

> The methode in the Wall-class is is finished and works. but i don´t know, how to call it for all members of that ArrayList.

You can iterate all the members of the list, and invoke the method on each.  There are multiple ways to implement the details.  But Java has no syntax for or sense of invoking a method on multiple objects via a single method-invocation expression.

But if you want to avoid a separate method call for each `Wall`, then consider interposing a level of indirection.  For example, create a `TileSet` class that contains all the details that should be common to many or all `Wall` instances, and give each `Wall` a reference to the same `TileSet` object.  You can then update data on which all the `Wall`s rely by modifying just the one `TileSet` object.

Answer (score -1):

i don´t need an answer any more.

```
for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++)
            {
                Wall wall = walls.get(i);
                wall.changeWallIce();
            }
```

this is what i needed.
Now i found it by my self.

Comment: You should still read the answers, because the enhanced for loops or the forEach() loops are better ways to loop in general: they work with any kind of collection, and are O(n) even for a linked list, whereas yours is not.

Comment: you found yourself the worst of the answers, for not bothering to read what people tried to tell you in order to help you

Comment: my solution does exactly the effect, what i want to see in my game. So why it is bad?

Comment: as i found, what i wrote, no answers of my question where displayed so far. so what should i read, if there is nothing to read in this moment?

Comment: now i changed to the forEach loop and that piece of code looks shorter and cleaner now (only my method-call in the curly braces of the loop now), but has the same effect ingame. is that the reason, why you say, it´s better?